# Error vb.net importar excel a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, excel

Me encuentro realizando una importación de datos de una planilla excel a un datagrid en VB.net

Cosa que logro hacer, si asigno el DataTable al DataGrid. Pero lo que realmente necesito es pasar campo a campo de la planilla al DataGrid.

Para realizar esto generé una función que llamada cargar_hoja, y es así.

```
Private Sub cargar_hoja(f As String, s As String)
    Dim dz As New DataTable
    Dim cont As Integer = 1

    If ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(f)) OrElse (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))) Then _
        Throw New ArgumentNullException()
    Try
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & s & "$]"
        Dim adaptador As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Conexion)
        Dim ds As New DataTable("Excel")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adaptador.Fill(ds)

        dt = limpiarFilas(ds)

        gvRegistros.DataSource = dt

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Esto funciona, el problema es cuando trato de pasar parametro a parametro para el datagrid, e intento hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
Private Sub cargar_hoja(f As String, s As String)
    Dim dz As New DataTable
    Dim cont As Integer = 1

    If ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(f)) OrElse (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))) Then _
        Throw New ArgumentNullException()
    Try
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & s & "$]"
        Dim adaptador As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Conexion)
        Dim ds As New DataTable("Excel")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adaptador.Fill(ds)

        dt = limpiarFilas(ds)

        While dt.Rows.Count > cont
            gvRegistros.Rows.Add(1)

            gvRegistros.Item("col1", cont).Value() = dz.Rows(cont)("B")
            gvRegistros.Item("col2", cont).Value() = dz.Rows(cont)("C")

            cont += 1
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub
```

El Error que arroja es: "No hay ninguna fila en posición 1"

Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: el error se da aca: gvRegistros.Rows.Add(1)?

Comment: Ya, el error ocurre acá

gvRegistros.Item("col1", cont).Value() = dz.Rows(cont)("B")

Comment: no sera porque la primer fila es la 0?

Comment: Si la dejo en cero, me arroja el mismo error pero en vez de decir 1 dice 0

Comment: ´podrias poner el stacktrace, y no el mensaje de error plano?

Comment: perdon la ignoracia, pero el stacktrace?

Comment: el error que sale, si le sacas el cactha.. el mensaje de error completo.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar el error. Resulta que el DataTable se llama dt y no dz. Eso era todo el error.